# How do I display two components with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, components

this is my first post on here! Just need some small help with a problem. Thanks!

I just started learning vue.js and I'm trying to get my second components template to display on the page. For some reason, vue isn't rendering my second component, only the first. I'm thinking something is wrong within the index file with `<education :data='data' />`. Do I need to create a different `<div id='app'>` and put the second component within it?

app.js:

```
// Fetch handler
function fetchData(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.log('Error retrieving data', error))
}

// Response error handler
function checkStatus(res) {
  if(res.ok) {
      return Promise.resolve(res);
  } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(res.statusText));
  }
}

(() => {
  // Define components.
  Vue.component('contact-info', {
    props: ['data'],
    template: `
      <div>
        <img v-bind:src='data.photo'>
        <h1>{{ data.name }}</h1>
        <p>{{ data.email }}</p><p>{{ data.phone }}</p>
        <p v-if='data'>{{ data.links[0] }}</p><p v-if='data'>{{ data.links[1] }}</p>
      </div>
    `
  });

  Vue.component('education', {
    props: ['data'],
    template: `
    <div>
      <h3>Education</h3>
      <div>
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      <div>
    <div>
    `
  });

  // Instantiate the app.
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        data: ''
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      fetchData('https://wip.journeygroup.com/intern-api/joshbryant.json')
          .then(jsonData => (this.data = jsonData))
    }
  });
})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Resume • Josh Bryant</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400;600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <contact-info :data='data' />
      <education :data='data' />
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but you shouldn't name a prop `data`, as [data](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) is a special object/function in a Vue instance. Name it `config`, `myData`, etc... Another detail: what is `fetchData`? Where is it defined/imported?

Comment: sorry, fetchData is defined aboce the vue function. It's basically just a fetch error handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your post shows *app.js* though the HTML looks for *main.js*, but I'll assume that's just a posting error since you've gotten some of it working.
- The reason it doesn't work is because custom HTML components require a closing tag and cannot be self-closing.  If you were using Vue CLI this would work anyway because the compiler would fix it, but not in a CDN implementation of Vue.  The first component will work but everything that follows will be invalid HTML since the first component isn't closed properly.

This will work:

```html
<div id="app">
  <contact-info :data="data"></contact-info>
  <education :data="data"></education>
</div>
```

**A couple of other suggestions**

- As @tao mentioned in comments, it's confusing to call your variable `data` in the root component, and similarly to call your props `data`.  These won't cause a problem but probably best to rename them all for clarity (so as not to be confused with the component's `data` option.)
- There's an invalid bullet character in the HTML `<title>` tag which you can replace with `&bullet;`
- It's best to use double quotes for your HTML attributes (the props use single quotes in your code)